# iOS turn-based game server costs

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm planning to create a turn-based game for iOS (and later android). What would service would you recommend for me (like PubNub)?

This might be a dummy question but is it completely free (for me) to publish a turn-based game in iOS using game center? So no server costs? If yes I guess this is the best way to create turn-based game for iOS only or how?

Comment: yes, game center is free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Game Center. For iOS this is the best guide for Game Center integration and usage of multiplayer games.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12

Some updates for using in with iOS version > 5 can be found here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/

As you can check by yourself Game Center integration is the minimal effort solution. You don't have to worry about connections, room creations, synchronization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using GameCenter. There's a WWDC session about this very topic:
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=506

Also see Terms and Conditions for GameCenter:
http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/gamecenter/lc/terms.html